# Reducing a flat morphism $\psi:X\rightarrow\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{C}}^1\;$ to $\;\psi|_{Y}: X\cap Y\rightarrow \mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{C}}^1$

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory, deformation-theory

Suppose $\psi: X\rightarrow \mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{C}}^1$ is a flat morphism, where $X\subseteq \mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{C}}^n$ with $X$ not needing to be smooth, with 
$\psi^{-1}(0)$ being a complete intersection.

> Question 1: Wouldn't that imply that $\psi^{-1}(c)$ is also a complete intersection for any $c\not=0$?

Now consider a subscheme $Y\subseteq \mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{C}}^n$, where $Y$ is a complete intersection.

> Question 2: If $Y\cap \psi^{-1}(0)$ is a complete intersection, then does that imply $Y\cap\psi^{-1}(c)$ is also a complete intersection, where $c\not=0$?

$$
$$
Here is the reason why I am thinking along the above lines. Consider 
$$
\psi: X = \operatorname{Spec}\left( 
    \dfrac{\mathbb{C}[x,y,z,w,a,b,c,d][t]}{
    \left<ab+cw+(1-t)d^2 \right> }  \right) 
     \longrightarrow \operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{C}[t].  
$$
Then not only is 
$\psi^{-1}(0)$ a complete intersection, $\psi^{-1}(1)$ is also a complete intersection.

Now take 
$$
Y= \operatorname{Spec}\left( 
    \dfrac{\mathbb{C}[x,y,z,w,a,b,c,d][t]}{
    \left<
    xy+zw, x+a+c
 \right> }  \right).  
$$
Then isn't it true that 
$$
Y\cap\psi^{-1}(0) = \operatorname{Spec} \left( 
    \dfrac{\mathbb{C}[x,y,z,w,a,b,c,d][t]}{
    \left<
    xy+zw, x+a+c, ab+cw+d^2
 \right> }  \right) 
$$
while 
$$
Y\cap\psi^{-1}(1) = \operatorname{Spec} \left( 
    \dfrac{\mathbb{C}[x,y,z,w,a,b,c,d][t]}{
    \left<
    xy+zw, x+a+c, ab+cw
 \right> }  \right)?  
$$
Please correct me if there is a typo anywhere in the example, or if some thought process isn't entirely correct.

$$
$$

Any thoughts, counter-examples, or references would be great since I have limited deformation theory notes on hand.

Comment: Please define "complete intersection".

Comment: What I mean by complete intersection is that if the fiber has dimension $r$, then the ideal defining the fiber can be generated by the the dimension of the ambient space (which is the dimension of $X$) minus $r$ minus the dimension of the base base (which is $1$). I will re-read what I wrote to make sure it is clear.

Comment: You should say complete intersection in which space.

Comment: I don't think the definition I gave is correct. Here's a simple example to explain what I mean in the above construction: consider $\mathbb{1}:\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{C}}^1\rightarrow \mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{C}}^1$ where $\mathbb{1}$ is the identity map. Then the fiber over $\mathbb{1}^{-1}(0)$ is a complete intersection of dimension $0$. In fact, over any other point in the base space, it is still a complete intersection.

Comment: I will repost my notion of complete intersection and in which space soon. What I wanted to do in this problem is come up with a flat map for this question  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166341/explicitly-constructing-a-certain-flat-family#comment383859_166341 using a slightly different strategy so that we obtain $\phi^{-1}((0,0,0))$ and $\phi^{-1}(t_1, t_2, t_3)$ (for some fixed $(t_1, t_2, t_3)$) as in that problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should make assumptions about the relative dimension of the new intersection over the target.

Anyway, you should also remember the following.  (See Hartshorne, Algebraic Geometry)  Whenever we have a morphism of schemes, say, of finite type over a field

$$f:X\to C$$ with $C$ a smooth curve and $X$ equidimensional, the morphism is flat if and only if no irreducible component of $X$ is contained within a fibre.

Milne, Etale Cohomology, in Chapter I, has a section on flat morphisms where this result is stated and, if I'm not mistaken, proven (or a reference is given).  Another beautiful reference is Mumford's The Red Book of Varieties and Schemes.