# the existence of a closed subset of $\mathbb{A}^8\times \mathbb{A}^1$ which is flat over $\mathbb{A}^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory

I've been doing some reading on deformation theory and one way it is used is to study singularities on varieties while perturbing the varieties. I would actually like to use deformation theory to construct a flat family linking the following two subschemes of $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{C}}^8$.

I would like to thank David Speyer who helped me to formulate this question from my other [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166341/explicitly-constructing-a-certain-flat-family).

> Does there exist a closed subset of $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{C}}^8\times \mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{C}}^1$, which is flat over $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{C}}^1$, whose fiber over $0$ is the set 
>   $$
> Z(x_1 y_1 + z_1 y_2, x_2 y_2 +z_3^2, x_3 y_3-z_3 y_2, x_1-x_2+x_3)
> $$
>   and whose fiber over $1$ is the set 
>   $$
> Z(x_1 y_1 + z_1 y_2,x_2 y_2, x_3 y_3-z_3 y_2, x_1-x_2+x_3)? 
> $$

Note that the only difference between the two sets is that the second polynomial is a monomial.

Comment: Dear math-visitor, I didn't think very hard about your particular equations, but is the obvious candidate $Z(x_1y_1 + z_1y_2, x_2 y_2 + (1-t)z_3^2, x_3y_3- z_3 y_2, x_1- x_2 + x_3)$ not flat over the $t$-line for some reason?  Regards,

Comment: Yes, that was what I was thinking of originally, but are there relatively simple/easy ways to check whether or not the map you wrote is flat?

Comment: Dear math-visitor, Since over a Dedekind domain flatness is the same as torsion free, you just have to check that the total space of the family doesn't have a component supported over some closed point of $\mathbb A^1$.  This could happen if your equations were sufficiently complicated, and conspired in some way to produce such a component for a particular value of $t$.  Probably they don't, and even if they did, one could likely modify my suggestion slightly so that the modified family is flat.   Regards,

Comment: @MattE This may be a naive question but suppose I am able to show that the obvious candidate is a flat morphism over the $t$-line. Then if the variety over $t=0$ is a complete intersection in $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{C}}^8$, then would the variety over $t=1$ be a complete intersection in $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{C}}^8$ as well? We could check this with a computer software for the above example, but there are more complicated examples where using a computer may be impossible or difficult.

Comment: Dear math-visitor, I don't have time to think this through right now; my suggestion would be to ask it as a separate question.  Best wishes,

Comment: Of course, and I will! =) Thank you for your time.